# How to Change Bottom Margins on Specific Page Style?

Tags: fancyhdr, geometry, pagestyle

I'm using fancyhdr.  My fancy page style has no footer (only footnotes).  However, on chapter titles, I am using a plain pagestyle, which has the footnote on the bottom.  In any case, I would like to be able to have different bottom margins on each of these page styles - 0.25in for the plain pagestyle, and 0.15in for the fancy page style.  How do you accomplish this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,top=0.25in,bottom=0.1in,left=0.75in,right=0.4in,paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{Right}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{Left}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My Chapter}

\blindtext[3]

\blindtext[3]

\blindtext[3]

\blindtext[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Page styles only change the contents, not the location.  In any case, what you seem to want is to change the text area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for fun.  You could also use table, or create a new float type.  It really doesn't matter unless you want to add another bottom float to the page.  Without a caption, it won't show up on the list of figures.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,top=0.25in,bottom=0.1in,left=0.75in,right=0.4in,paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE,RO]{Right}
\fancyhead[LE,LO]{Left}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{\fancyhf{}}% plain=empty

%\makeatletter
%\let\ps@plain=\ps@empty
%\makeatother

\newcommand{\addpageno}{\begin{figure}[b]
\makebox[\textwidth]{\thepage}
\end{figure}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{My Chapter}
\addpageno

\blindtext[3]

\blindtext[3]

\blindtext[3]

\blindtext[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I was skeptical of this at first.  However, I tried it out and, lo and behold, it worked!  A suggested improvement (which I did in my own file) would be to add the titlesec package, and stick \addpageno to the actual chapter command.

Comment: Or modify \chapter directly.  There are several ways it can be done, if you need to.