# Add same text at bottom of several pages

Tags: footer

I'm working on my thesis document, and the university requires the following disclaimer be at the bottom of all pages of the Acknowledgments section.

*Acknowledgements reflect the view of the author and are not endorsed by the committee members or the university.*

I have attempted to add the following:

`\let\thefootnote\relax\footnote{Acknowledgments reflect the views of the author and are not endorsed by committee members or the university.}`

but this does not keep the footer on all pages of this section.

Is there any way to keep a running note such as this for a certain section?

Comment: I would use a bottom float, either figure, table or create a new float type.  Since counter bottomnumber=1 (default), you can add one for each page at the beginning.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469384/how-to-change-bottom-margins-on-specific-page-style/469393?r=SearchResults&s=2|41.0722#469393

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did add a simple table float that can be placed inline when needed. Hacky, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhf{} 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\lfoot{\thepage}
%\rfoot{\vspace{-.8cm}\Footer\\vspace{.24cm}
\footnotesize Acknowledgments reflect the views of the author and are not endorsed by committee members or the university.

\begin{document}
…
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is this going to edit all footers or just the ones in that particular section? It looks to me like this changes the footers for the entire document.

Comment: Try this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91219/change-header-and-footer-to-only-a-group-of-pages

Comment: After the acknowledgements section you can revert it with `\rfoot{}`. And, by the way, these are deprecated commands. I would prefer `fancyfoot[R]{...}`.